# Minecraft 1.10.2 Problem: Expected token 'm'

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making an adventure map that includes a sort of redstone clock.
I want to set a command block connected to the clock and have it spawn items.
Unfortunately, I am not very skilled in command blocks and could use a little help.

This is my command:

> /setblock 138 93 254 minecraft:command_block 0 replace
>   {Command:"/summon Item 140 115 245
>   {Item:{id:"minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1}}"}

When I execute the command, it returns with this output:

Data tag parsing failed: `Unexpected token 'm' at: minecraft:gold_nugget",Count:1}}"`

Can anyone please help me?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the middle set of quote marks around the ID by putting backslashes (\) before them, like this:

> /setblock 138 93 254 minecraft:command_block 0 replace {Command:"/summon Item 140 115 245 {Item:{id:\"minecraft:gold_nugget\",Count:1}}"}

Otherwise the command parser thinks the block's command is "/summon Item 140 115 245 {Item:{id:" then seeing the word minecraft: when there should have been a close curly bracket (}). Backslashes tell programs to ignore the special function of a symbol and treat it like any other part of a string.
As an alternative, you could enter "/give @p minecraft:command_block" and input the summon command manually.